# Cocos2d-js 3.10(android) hangout some seconds each approximately 20 seconds

Tags: android, garbage-collection, cocos2d-js, chipmunk

I'm making a game, using cocos2d-js 3.10. on android device, my game always stuck about 1->2 second each 20 seconds, it makes players feeling uncomfortable. I'm making a game shooting helicopter, i think may be because of cocos garbage collection or Chipmunk body manager clear or doing something after a period time. i just watch cpu and ram on win32, the graph is normal. is there anything like setting garbage collection time or setting chipmunk manager time.